# Unable to open PDF file through intent programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have an app where on button click, access should be provided to browse and open the PDF files stored in the internal memory of the device.I tried various codes but i get an toast saying "Cannot display PDF". I don't get any errors in logs. I use android version 7.0 device. Attached my code below: please help:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have included this in Oncreate:

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

This is how called the method:

```
  linear_pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            pdf.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));


                            openPdf(getContext(), Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");



                            communication.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are giving correct PATH for file ?

Comment: @HeisenBrg: Yes

Comment: Do you have read permission to external storage?

Comment: @AIMINPAN: i have added the following permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: adding permission to manifest is not enough for Android 7.0, you need to request permission at run time.

Comment: @AIMINPAN: Can you please share the code for that or any reference link?

Comment: starting 6.0 you need runtime permission. see https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions

Comment: @AIMINPAN: Hi, i tried it in android 5.0 device, but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have an app installed which can view pdf?

Comment: I have PDF Viewer app in  android 7.0 device not in 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
public void openPdf(Context context, String path){
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose");
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
                if (resInfo.size() > 0) {
                    try {
                        context.startActivity(openInChooser);
                    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "PDF apps are not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // PDF apps are not installed
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "PDF apps are not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Call this method:

```
openPdf(getApplicationContext(), Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, what parameters should i pass for the openPdf() method? (ie) for context and path

Comment: I have done the same, but no action occurs on button click. I guess the method is not called .

Comment: check my updated question, i have called the method in that following manner. Is it right?

Comment: The method is called, but have you added the Read External Storage permission in the manifest?

Comment: I have put log messages to check whether the openpdf method is called. But the messages are not printed in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

For opening one specific file:

```
  File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/your_directory/" + "your_file_name" + ".pdf");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try{
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No required app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Check directory, this one works.

Comment: Hi, what is "your directory" path? i used :                         File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/storage/emulated/" + "new" + ".pdf"); , but it says cannot open file.

Comment: File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/issuefiles/" + "SR345" + ".pdf"); , I think storage/emulated is wrong path, and that's why you can't open your file

Comment: I get /storage/emulated/ path from this line "(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() "

Comment: I gave the exact path, but it shows an alert "Cannot open document"

Comment: just go to "My Files", it should be your ExternalStorageDirectory and then, look for your folder. You can add now: getExternalStorageDirectory + "/your_directory/" + "/next_directory/" //and next directories if it's deeper

Comment: try without .getAbsolutePath()

Comment: File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/new.pdf");
This is my code, but it still says cannot open document

Comment: try to debug, and check if directory is ok, because, you're gonna get "cannot open document" if app can't find document inside specific folder

Answer (score 0):

For opening pdf file from local storage add prefix in url.

```
private void openPdf(File file) {

        try {

            String url = file.getAbsolutePath();

            String u = "file:///" + url;

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(u));
            startActivity(i);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```